# How to integrate InApp Purchase in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I want to use inapp purchase in my application.FOR inapp I have seen so many tutorial and I have get demo project for that.,but the problem is that when I am clicking in google developer console, it's asking for payment and I only want its public key without payment, I don't want to publish my   application on googleplay. two things I want to do

1. how to create my public key for InAPP Purchase api.
2. from where I can get my key for inapp?/

I have seen this links
[here](http://startandroid.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/android-in-app-purchase-tutorial/)
&
[here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial)

and here is the image snippest [image: here]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best tutorials are those of developer.android.com. So first read this:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html
You definitely want to add this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

to your manifest so that you can later add your keys on the developer console

Comment: sir,that is ok but how i get key from google devloper console.

Comment: @M.D. SIR how can i get my devlopeer key

Comment: If you upload the apk with the developer console you can create your keys

Comment: thankyou sir.,i have created but i am getting another error.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551887/android-invalid-key-specification-exception

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not test Google InApp purchases without publishing application on play-store whether it is in Alpha Testing Mode.

In your case if you really need to test InApp purchases in your application then below are the steps to do so:

1. Sign-up on [Google Play Console](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinrrDc6ZfYAhVLQ48KHX0FBCEQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fapps%2Fpublish%2Fsignup%2F&usg=AOvVaw3XoC3mI-cSBwjOabvcQ-Ej) (Paid Once)
2. Complete your [merchant account](https://support.google.com/payments/merchant/answer/7161426?hl=en) (Required for InApp)
3. Get billing-key (Go to Setting->API Access) from play developer console
4. Use this key into your application to purchase something from
   play-store ([Follow these steps](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/implement-in-app-purchase-version-3))
5. Create application on Play Console and Fill all store listing data
   for same application
6. Create in-app purchases products on console
7. Generate signed application and publish it to alpha
8. Add some [testing users](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTp-3-6pfYAhVCs48KHdTFAXQQFgg6MAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fgoogle%2Fplay%2Fbilling%2Fbilling_testing.html&usg=AOvVaw1SmpV1AMIR_Z0lgrk1sSsR) for demo testing of your application
9. After final testing publish it to production for all users

Thanks