# android invalid key specification exception?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

i am using InApp Purchase api in my application ,where i have made an demo project ,in which i have taken one button,when we click on button i am getting this screen here
[image: here]

after then when i click on buy button an dialog shows that "payement sucessful",the image is here[image]

after showing this dialog,my application get forceclosed.,i am getting error at this line

```
public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {
    try {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Base64DecoderException.", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

here is my logcat
[image]

Comment: did any one get any solution pleas ehelp me.........:(

Comment: @DigveshPatel sir have you tried this......:(

Comment: ya you can see in my app timecop

Comment: @DigveshPatel what is app timecop???

Comment: my app which r in market in which i used inapp purchase